# Cannot read the property of react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component for multi step page setup. It stores the state of

```
export default class CreateArticle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            step: 1
        };
    }
    saveValues(fields) {
        fieldValues = Object.assign({}, fieldValues, fields);
    }
    nextStep() {
        this.setState({
            step : this.state.step +1
        })
    }
    prevStep() {
        this.setState({
            step: this.state.step -1
        })
    }
    render() {

        switch (this.state.step) {
            case 1:
                return <CreateArticleWysiwyg nextStep={this.nextStep} saveValues={this.saveValues}/>
            case 2:
                return <CreateArticlePublish nextStep={this.nextStep} saveValues={this.saveValues}/>
        }
    }
}
```

One of the component where I am calling the `props` functions.

```
export default class CreateArticleWysiwyg extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            is_header: false,
            is_quote: false
        };
    }
    saveAndContinue = () => {
        var data = {
            article_body: this.refs.article_body.value
        }
        this.props.saveValues(data);
        this.props.nextStep();
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <header id="create-article-wysiwyg-header">
                    <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
                    <button id="confirm" onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>Ok</button>
                    <span class="clear_both"></span>
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I visit the page, the page is displayed with its child component (i.e `<CreateArticleWysiwyg />`). But when I press ok (which fires the saveAndContinue()), I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'step' of undefined

What am I doing wrong? Your help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are not binding your callbacks in `CreateArticle`. Either use the assignment syntax + arrow function like in `CreateArticleWysiwyg`, or bind in constructor.

Comment: Yes. Sorry! I forgot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the `constructor`method of `CreateArticle` you should add `this.nextStep=this.nextStep.bind(this)` to bind the function's context to the component instead of to the click event.